# É possível detectar a tecla pressionada em Lua?

Tags: lua

Trabalhando em modo terminal, eu tenho controle sobre as coordenadas de tela onde o texto será exibido, no entanto preciso *detectar se uma tecla foi pressionada*, sem que a mesma **ecoe** na tela.

Existe alguma função ou biblioteca que me permita detectar isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Diretamente, de forma pronta, até onde eu sei, não. É possível fazer isto em C e expor para Lua acessar. De fato existem alguma bibliotecas que já fizeram isto. Exemplo [NTLua](http://ntlua.sourceforge.net/en/func.html#getkey).

Achei este [outro exemplo](http://www.pjb.com.au/comp/lua/readkey.html) mas não sei se ele funciona como você deseja.

[Aqui](http://www.playwithlua.com/?p=49) há outra tentativa.

Answer (score -2):

Sim, é possível, você precisa adicionar  uma linha com o código 'Runtime:addEventListener('key', minha_funcao)'.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O exemplo apresentado na pergunta é valido apenas para versão do interpretador embutido com [Solar2D Corona SDK](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/detectEvents/index.html#event-listeners). Aproveite e leia [answer] e faça o nosso [tour].